# Explicitly set image compression filter

Tags: c++, c, image, pdf, libharu

According to [PDF format spec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#Imaging_model), it has various image compression filters including **CCITTFaxDecode**.

I'm using `libharu` and need to explicitly set compression filter to CCITTFaxDecode for all images in the generated PDF.

**How can I tell `libHaru` to use CCITT compression for images in PDF?**

Below is the where I am currently.

From the `libHaru` documentation, it has [`HPDF_SetCompressionMode()` function](http://libharu.sourceforge.net/document_handling.html#HPDF_SetCompressionMode_) which has the argument named `mode`. The argument has the `HPDF_COMP_IMAGE` option enabling images compression. But it's not clear how to choose which compressor to use.

Another thing, among `libHaru` source files there is CCITT compressor (`hpdf_image_ccitt.c`), but I can't figure out how to explicitly set it as the compressor for images.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My read of the source in hpdf_image_ccitt.c is that the CCITT G4 encoder is selected automatically for eligible instances if `HPDF_COMP_IMAGE` is enabled. See https://github.com/libharu/libharu/blob/d84867ebf9f3de6afd661d2cdaff102457fbc371/src/hpdf_image_ccitt.c#L779 for where this looks to be the case.

Note that only black & white (1 bit per pixel) images can be CCITT encoded.